# Does case statement work in bigquery sandbox?

Tags: sql, case

I'm getting this error when I tried to run the query:

> No matching signature for operator CASE; all THEN/ELSE arguments must be coercible to a common type but found: BOOL, STRING; actual argument types (WHEN THEN) ELSE: (BOOL BOOL) STRING at [3:2]

**Query **

```
SELECT  
 customer_id,
 CASE 
  WHEN name = 'Devadas Sloan' THEN name = 'Devdas Sloan'
  ELSE name
  END AS new_name
FROM `valid-cell-380712.customer_table_gda.customer_table`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do an assignment inside the `CASE` statement, when all you need is to generate an if and else value.  Use this version:

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    CASE WHEN name = 'Devadas Sloan' THEN name ELSE name END AS new_name
FROM valid-cell-380712.customer_table_gda.customer_table;
```

Of course, the above `CASE` expression just returns `name` in all cases.  It would make more sense if you wanted to replace `Devadas Sloan` with some other name, e.g. use:

```sql
SELECT
    customer_id,
    CASE WHEN name = 'Devadas Sloan' THEN 'D Sloan' ELSE name END AS new_name
FROM valid-cell-380712.customer_table_gda.customer_table;
```